# numpy sum several columns

Tags: python, numpy

I want to read files with the following structure:

```
1         3      7        34
1         4      3         6
1         8      2        10
2         9     35        11
2        10     12        24
...
```

the number of columns change from one file to another, and I want to sum all the values of the columns for 1, 2, etc.

So the results should be something like

```
1       15     12      50
2       19     37      45
...
```

I have started coding something like:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

inFile = sys.argv[1]

A = np.genfromtxt(inFile, delimiter=None)

a = np.size(A,1) #get the number of columns

i = np.nonzero(np.diff(A[:, 0]))[0] + 1
i = np.insert(i, 0, 0)

c1 = A[i, 0]
for l in range(3,a+1):
    c = np.add.reduceat(A[:, l], i)
    result = np.c_[c1, c]
```

How can I do this with numpy?

Comment: Use `np.add.reduceat` with axis param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Loopy `numpy` method**

This is not the most beautiful way, and there is likely a vectorized approach that is much more elegant and efficient, but you can do the following with a list comprehension. See the bottom for benchmark.

Given a 2-d array `x`:

```
>>> x
array([[ 1,  3,  7, 34],
       [ 1,  4,  3,  6],
       [ 1,  8,  2, 10],
       [ 2,  9, 35, 11],
       [ 2, 10, 12, 24]])


np.vstack([np.insert(x[x[:,0] == i][:,1:].sum(axis=0),0,i)
           for i in np.unique(x[:,0])])
```

Returns:

```
array([[ 1, 15, 12, 50],
       [ 2, 19, 47, 35]])
```

**`pandas` suggestion**

For this sort of tabular data, though, you might want to consider `pandas`. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(x)

>>> df
   0   1   2   3
0  1   3   7  34
1  1   4   3   6
2  1   8   2  10
3  2   9  35  11
4  2  10  12  24


>>> df.groupby(0).sum()

    1   2   3
0            
1  15  12  50
2  19  47  35
```

You would also easily be able to get it back to a `numpy` array:

```
>>> df.groupby(0).sum().reset_index().values
array([[ 1, 15, 12, 50],
       [ 2, 19, 47, 35]])
```

**Benchmarks**

To my surprise, both methods are comparable as far as speed, with my loopy `numpy` method narrowly beating the `pandas` method: on a large array of shape `(100000, 100)`, the loopy `numpy` method took about 0.1 seconds on average, and the `pandas` method took about 0.13 seconds on average

```
import timeit

x = np.random.randint(0,10,(100000, 100))

def np_method(arr = x):
    return np.vstack([np.insert(arr[arr[:,0] == i][:,1:].sum(axis=0),0,i)
                      for i in np.unique(arr[:,0])])

def pd_method(df = pd.DataFrame(x)):
    return df.groupby(0).sum().reset_index().values

>>> timeit.timeit(pd_method, number = 100) / 100
0.12673938989639283

>>> timeit.timeit(np_method, number = 100) / 100
0.09724574089050293
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried the numpy method and works very well

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fully vectorized method, assuming IDs are sorted. Idea:

1. Compute cumsum of the entire dataset.
2. Take the last row for each ID.
3. Take difference of successive ids.
4. Reindex.

---

```
def tally(xs):
    # index of the last id in each group
    id_ix = np.searchsorted(xs[:, 0], np.unique(xs[:, 0]), "right") - 1
    # compute cumulative sum over all ids;
    # drop every line that is not final for some id
    csums = xs.cumsum(0)[id_ix]
    # take differences between adjacent groups
    csums[1:] = np.diff(csums, axis=0)
    # recover old IDs
    csums[:, 0] = xs[id_ix, 0]
    return csums

# ys.shape == (1_000_000, 10)
# In [377]: %timeit q.np_method(q.ys)
# 5.74 s ± 47.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# In [378]: %timeit q.tally(q.ys)
# 143 ms ± 1.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I like this method, but I seem to have gotten vastly different results as far as benchmarks: with `x.shape = (1000000, 10)`, `tally(x)` took on average 0.23 seconds, and `np_method(x)` took on average 0.07 seconds. `numpy` version: `'1.13.3'`

Comment: Weird. I was using floats, not ints in my test. Numpy version 1.14.3.

Comment: @sacul I think I get it. I used `1000` ids in my test. If I use `10` as in your test, your method is faster.

Comment: Oh interesting... Well, I guess it depends on OP's requirements, but in any case, you have my upvote :)

Comment: Thanks, likewise!